# How to get docs from Mongodb collection where based on unique array values and date/time

Tags: jquery, node.js, database, mongodb, chat

I have developed a chat application where the message collection looks as below. On the chat page, I need to show the list of latest message for each user I sent or received a message. If I was a chat initiator, then my id will be in sender_id and if the other party initiated the chat, then my id will be in `receiver_id`. As additional, Both our ids will be in "chatusers" element.

I am not sure how to write a query to get collection of documents with latest message for each unique user timestamp, assuming that my id is "63f6f203ed79d9c6f7da979d"

```json
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("64366093b5ad8b8c2d136197"),
  "sender_id" : "63f61a8a062d19324083de23",
  "receiver_id" : "6411b295d14516a007ddd2d1",
  "message" : "How are you  ",
  "chatusers" : [
    "63f61a8a062d19324083de23",
    "6411b295d14516a007ddd2d1"
  ],
  "timestamp" : "2023-04-12T07:41:07.220Z"
}, {
  "_id" : ObjectId("643687428ee27489059a9ff6"),
  "sender_id" : "63f61a8a062d19324083de23",
  "receiver_id" : "63f6f203ed79d9c6f7da979d",
  "message" : "@ress. How much is the price",
  "chatusers" : [
    "63f61a8a062d19324083de23",
    "63f6f203ed79d9c6f7da979d"
  ],
  "timestamp" : "2023-04-12T10:26:10.008Z"
}, {
  "_id" : ObjectId("6436a189bc4cec7e27e0d67d"),
  "sender_id" : "63f61a8a062d19324083de23",
  "receiver_id" : "63f6f203ed79d9c6f7da979d",
  "message" : "Hello Allan",
  "chatusers" : [
    "63f61a8a062d19324083de23",
    "63f6f203ed79d9c6f7da979d"
  ],
  "timestamp" : "2023-04-12T12:18:17.883Z"
}, {
  "_id" : ObjectId("6436a1971a943bbab769f252"),
  "sender_id" : "63f6f203ed79d9c6f7da979d",
  "receiver_id" : "63f61a8a062d19324083de23",
  "message" : "Hi",
  "chatusers" : [
    "63f6f203ed79d9c6f7da979d",
    "63f61a8a062d19324083de23"
  ],
  "timestamp" : "2023-04-12T12:18:31.702Z"
}, {
  "_id" : ObjectId("6436a1be1a943bbab769f253"),
  "sender_id" : "63f6f203ed79d9c6f7da979d",
  "receiver_id" : "63f61a8a062d19324083de23",
  "message" : "hi",
  "chatusers" : [
    "63f6f203ed79d9c6f7da979d",
    "63f61a8a062d19324083de23"
  ],
  "timestamp" : "2023-04-12T12:19:10.972Z"
}, {
  "_id" : ObjectId("6436a1ef1a943bbab769f254"),
  "sender_id" : "6433c8d8cd26bdeb35d4c04a",
  "receiver_id" : "63f6f203ed79d9c6f7da979d",
  "message" : "Hi",
  "chatusers" : [
    "6433c8d8cd26bdeb35d4c04a",
    "63f6f203ed79d9c6f7da979d"
  ],
  "timestamp" : "2023-04-12T12:19:59.356Z"
}, {
  "_id" : ObjectId("6436a2ea1a943bbab769f255"),
  "sender_id" : "6433c8d8cd26bdeb35d4c04a",
  "receiver_id" : "63f6f203ed79d9c6f7da979d",
  "message" : "Ress",
  "chatusers" : [
    "6433c8d8cd26bdeb35d4c04a",
    "63f6f203ed79d9c6f7da979d"
  ],
  "timestamp" : "2023-04-12T12:24:10.223Z"
}, {
  "_id" : ObjectId("6436a2ec1a943bbab769f256"),
  "sender_id" : "6433c8d8cd26bdeb35d4c04a",
  "receiver_id" : "63f6f203ed79d9c6f7da979d",
  "message" : "Hi",
  "chatusers" : [
    "6433c8d8cd26bdeb35d4c04a",
    "63f6f203ed79d9c6f7da979d"
  ],
  "timestamp" : "2023-04-12T12:24:12.820Z"
}, {
  "_id" : ObjectId("6436a2f11a943bbab769f257"),
  "sender_id" : "6433c8d8cd26bdeb35d4c04a",
  "receiver_id" : "63f6f203ed79d9c6f7da979d",
  "message" : "Bro",
  "chatusers" : [
    "6433c8d8cd26bdeb35d4c04a",
    "63f6f203ed79d9c6f7da979d"
  ],
  "timestamp" : "2023-04-12T12:24:17.503Z"
}, {
  "_id" : ObjectId("6436a3761a943bbab769f258"),
  "sender_id" : "6433c8d8cd26bdeb35d4c04a",
  "receiver_id" : "63f61a8a062d19324083de23",
  "message" : "Hi",
  "chatusers" : [
    "6433c8d8cd26bdeb35d4c04a",
    "63f61a8a062d19324083de23"
  ],
  "timestamp" : "2023-04-12T12:26:30.972Z"
}, {
  "_id" : ObjectId("6436a3771a943bbab769f259"),
  "sender_id" : "63f61a8a062d19324083de43",
  "receiver_id" : "63f6f203ed79d9c6f7da979d",
  "message" : "Hello Allan",
  "chatusers" : [
    "63f61a8a062d19324083de23",
    "6433c8d8cd26bdeb35d4c04a"
  ],
  "timestamp" : "2023-04-12T12:26:31.855Z"
}
```

I tried aggregate method and able to retrieve unique ids from the "chatuser" element, but, not sure how to proceed and get the latests messages for each user.

```js
db.getCollection("messages").aggregate([
 { $match: { chatusers : {$in:['63f6f203ed79d9c6f7da979d']}} },
  {
    $project: {
      chatusers: 1,
      _id: 0
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$chatusers"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$chatusers"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      allchatusers: {
        "$addToSet": "$_id"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

I want to get the document collection for the following unique chatusers from the message collection.

```json
{
  "_id" : null,
  "allchatusers" : [
    "63f61a8a062d19324083de23",
    "63f6f203ed79d9c6f7da979d",
    "6433c8d8cd26bdeb35d4c04a"
  ]
}
```